# Incrementing a registration number composed of strings and letter

Tags: c#, .net

My problem is similar to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858951/increment-a-number-within-a-string-c) but slightly different. I have a registration number  having the form :

14AAA999 : 14 is the current year, each A represents a caracter and each 9 represents a digit.
I know how to extract a number from a string but I would like to increment also the letters. Here is what I would like to achieve :

The first guy registered on the year 2014 would have this registration number : 14AAA000, the second 14AAA001, ..., until 14AAA999 and then it would become 14AAB000, and so on until 14ZZZ999. I'm looking for a good way to increment the letters for each overflow.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you want that logic in the app layer or the data layer?

Comment: When the string is equal to `14AAZ999` the next value will be? `14ABA001`?

Comment: @Steve I'm guessing it will be `14ABA000`

Comment: There's two parts to your problem:  the actual logic to increment the number and a method to deal with contention (of two processes create a "new" registration before either of them is saved to the DB).

Comment: @Stanley, I'm trying to implement it in the Business Layer, so yea we can say in the Data Layer.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Yes Absolutely !

Comment: @Stanley Thanks, I 'll try to find more information on the contention part. I missed this one.

Comment: @Joey by "data layer" I mean the database itself.

Comment: @DStanley Oh sorry, then it's in the Application Layer! I'm not good with DB programming and SQL Queries. I designed everything using EF code-first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have a Number that is two separate bases.  For the first 3 digits you are base 10 in the next base 26 where A = 0.  you can simply create a number convert that converts from your representation to to other.  This is slightly different than ISE solution.

```
class foo
{
    public static string ToRep(int Year,int Num)
    {
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(Year.ToString());
        SB.Append(":");
        int DecPart = Num % 1000;
        int Base26Part = Num / 1000;            
        for(int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++)
        {
            char NewChar =(char)( 'A'+ Base26Part % 26); 
            Base26Part /= 26;                
            SB.Insert(3,NewChar); 
        }
        SB.Append(DecPart.ToString("000"));
        return SB.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's a very smart and clean way of doing it. Sometimes we tend to forget that we've spend several years learning arithmetics at uni and that it can be useful. I will go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

```
char[] minValues { "14AAA000" }
char[] maxValues { "99ZZZ999" }

int index = input.Length - 1;

do
{
  if (input[index] < maxValues[index])
  {
    input[index]++;
    for (int j = index + 1; j < input.Length)
      input[j] := minValues[j];
    break;
  }
  else
    index--;
} while (true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is the kind of inspiration I was looking for.